# Is there a pattern for compiler-enforced implementation completeness regarding a new member?

Tags: c++, compilation

Imagine a larger project, containing some parameter struct:

```
struct pars {
    int foo;
};
```

With this struct as parameter, other functionality is implemented, e.g.:

```
// (de)serialization into different formats
static pars   FromString(string const &text);
static string ToString(pars const &data);
static pars   FromFile(string const &filename);
// [...]

// comparison / calculation / verification
static bool   equals(pars l, pars r);
static pars   average(pars a, pars b);
static bool   isValid(pars p);
// [...]

// you-name-it
```

Now imagine a new member needs to be added to that struct:

```
struct pars {
    int foo;
    int bar; // new member
};
```

Is there a design pattern to break the build or issue warnings until all neccessary code places are adapted?

**Example:**

- If I were to change `int foo` into `string foo`, I would not miss any code line which needs to be changed.
- If `int foo` would need to change into `unsigned int foo`, I could rename `foo` to `foo_u` and have the compiler point me to where adaptations are neccessary.

One partial solution is to make the members `private` and settable only from the constructor, which has to be called with all parameters:

```
pars::pars(int _foo, int _bar)
 : foo(_foo), bar(_bar)
{ }
```

This ensures the correct *creation* of pars, but not the *usage* - so this catches missing adaptations in `FromString()`, but not in `ToString()`.

Unit tests would reveal such problems only during the test (I'm searching for a compile time method), and also only the (de)serialization part, and not that new `bar` is being considered everywhere (in the comparison / calculation / verification / ... functions as well).

Comment: Feel free to suggest matching tags, or a better headline.

Comment: already solved with boost.serialization and many others.

Answer (score 3):

Decouple the streaming operations from the source or destinations of the streams.

A very simple example:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

struct pars
{
    int foo;
    int bar;

    static constexpr auto current_version = 2;
};

std::istream &deserialise(std::istream &is, pars &model)
{
    int version;

    is >> version;
    is >> model.foo;
    if (version > 1) {
        is >> model.bar;
    }
    return is;
}

std::ostream &serialise(std::ostream &os, const pars &model)
{
    os << model.current_version << " ";
    os << model.foo << " ";
//    a version 2 addition
    os << model.bar<< " ";
    return os;
}

static pars FromString(std::string const &text)
{
    std::istringstream iss(text);
    auto result = pars();
    deserialise(iss, result);
    return result;
}

static std::string ToString(pars const &data)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    serialise(oss, data);
    return oss.str();
}

static pars FromFile(std::string const &filename)
{
    auto file = std::ifstream(filename);
    auto result = pars();
    deserialise(file, result);
    return result;
}
```

Also have a look at:

boost.serialization http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html

cereal https://github.com/USCiLab/cereal

etc.

Comment: The use of a `constexpr` version inspired me to think that OP could write `static_asserts` in the (de)serialization functions on the version number.

Comment: @AndyG The thinking here is that software checking allows later versions to read the archives written by earlier versions and supply appropriate defaults.

Comment: The question is not mainly about serialization (see edit). But I like the idea of a `constexpr` version member (although `static const int` is a constexpr even in C+99) in combination with `static_assert`: It adds little extra code and no template magic, and it is self-explanatory. Disadvantage: One can easily 'forget' to add the `static_assert` to one's own code.

Answer (score 3):

A pattern that enforces this would be a for-each-member operation.

Pick a name, like `members_of`.  Using ADL and a tag, make `members_of(tag<T>)` return a tuple of integral constant member pointers to the members of `T`.

This has to be written once.  Then it can be used many spots.

I will write it in C++17 as in 14 and earlier it is just more verbose.

```
template<class T>struct tag_t{constexpr tag_t(){}};
template<class T>constexpr tag_t<t> tag{};
template<auto X>using val_t=std::integral_constant<decltype(X), X>;
template<auto X>constexpr val_k<X> val{};

struct pars {
  int foo;
  friend constexpr auto members_of( tag_t<pars> ){
    return std::make_tuple( val<&pars::foo> );
  }
};
```

When you add a member you must also add it to the friend `members_of`.

```
template<class...Fs>
struct overload:Fs...{
  using Fs::operator()...;
  overload(Fs...fs):Fs(std::move(fs))... {}
};
```

`overload` lets you overload lambdas.

Finally write a foreach_tuple_element.

```
static pars   FromString(string const &text){
  pars retval;
  foreach_tuple_element( members_of(tag<pars>), overload{
    [&](val_t<&pars::foo>){
      // code to handle pars.foo
    }
  });
  return retval;
}
```

when you add a new member `bar` to both `pars` and `members_of`, the above code breaks as the foreach cannot find an overload for `val_t<&pars::bar>`.

```
static pars   FromString(string const &text){
  pars retval;
  foreach_tuple_element( members_of(tag<pars>), overload{
    [&](val_t<&pars::foo>){
      // code to handle pars.foo
    },
    [&](val_t<&pars::bar>){
      // code to handle pars.bar
    }
  });
  return retval;
}
```

and now it would compile.

---

For serialization / deserialization specifically, you want a single method *for both* (where the type of one arg says if it is in or out), and string to/from is just a special case of serialization/deserialization.

```
template<class A, class Self,
  std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<pars, std::decay_t<Self>>{}, int> =0
>
friend void Archive(A& a, Self& self) {
  ArchiveBlock(a, archive_tag("pars"), 3, [&]{
    Archive(a, self.foo);
    Archive(a, self.bar);
  });
}
```

this is an example of how a unified serialize/deserialize method (without the above member pointers) works.  You override `Archive` on your output stream and on `primitive const&`, on your input stream and `primitive&`.

For almost everything else, you use common structure for both reading and writing from the Archive.  This keeps the structure of your input and output identical.

`ArchiveBlock( Archive&, tag, tag version, lambda )` wraps the `lambda` in whatever archiving block structure you have.  As an example, your archive blocks might have length information in their header, allowing earlier deserializers to skip over added data at the end.  It would also both read and write blocks; on writing, it would write out the block header and whatever else before writing the body (maybe keeping track of length and backing up to record length once they know it).  On reading, it would ensure the tag exists (and deal with missing tags however you choose; skip?) and fast forward over newer block contents if you want to support older readers reading what newer writers write.

---

In more general cases where you need to keep code aligned with data this answer might solve things.  Serialization and deserialization are very special cases, because unlike most bits of C++ code you have to future-proof the binary layout of *everything*.  It is like writing library interfaces; there is lots more care required.

Comment: The question is not mainly about serialization (see edit). Just interested: Can you elaborate a bit more on `you want a single method for both`?

Comment: @MartinHennings Augmented